# baposter with XeTeX

Tags: xetex, baposter

I can't set the header color in [`baposter`](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/). I don't get any error message.

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[landscape,a0paper]{baposter}

\begin{document}
\begin{poster}{
headerborder=closed,
headerColorOne=red} % should set the header color to red
{}
{title}
{\textsc{Author}}
{}

\headerbox{Text}{name=text,column=0,row=0}{Text}

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

And this is result, with no red header.

[image: bapost]

EDIT:

I'm running XeTeX and this seems to be the problem. How can I get this working with XeTeX?

Comment: With an up-to-date TeX Live 2014 distro and this version of [`baposter.cls`](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/baposter/baposter.cls), I get a red gradient background in the header. Try updating your distribution and using the latest version of `baposter`.

Comment: I was running XeLaTeX. I tried PDFLaTeX and the output is as expected.

Comment: I get the same output as you do with `xelatex`.

Comment: I also get the yellow header with `xelatex`. I also have font issues with baposter and xelatex.

Comment: As of Tex Live 2018, there are still colour problems with `baposter.cls` and `xelatex`.

Comment: I think this might be [this bug](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/520).